# why does maven don't download jar files for newer versions of hibernate-core?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

So I'm new to maven and watching a course on how to download hibernate-core using maven,
and he went online and got the 5.2.11 version

[image]

but I downloaded the latest one 6.1.4

[image]

the thing is when he opened his local files the jar files were there like this:

[image]

but my version only downloaded these files, even when I removed the type pom:

[image]

and when I tried the older version it worked for me, so my question is why did maven do that, and does it make any problem?
also, can I now use hibernate if I don't have an internet connection, or do I need to download the jar files anyway?

NOTE: I'm using Eclipse

Comment: You typed `<type>pom</type>`  That means it will only download the pom

Comment: I tried removing the `<type>pom</type>` but it didn't help

Comment: What else did you do?

Comment: Did you run a `mvn` command after you removed the `<type>pom</type>`?

Comment: I used "Update Project" in eclipce

Answer (score 0):

Your dependency is declared in a different way from the [official documentation](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-core/6.1.4.Final/jar). They don't specify a `<type>pom</type>`, which may be the cause of your problem.

They have it like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>6.1.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Remove the type and rebuild the project.

Comment: I tried removing the `<type>pom</type>` but it didn't help, also what is the difference between org.hibernate and org.hibernate.orm does it affect any thing?

Comment: No, there is no connection between the `groupId` and the package name, I edited my answer to avoid confusion, this is just a convention. But changing the pom type and rebuilding the project should fix the problem, at least the JARs should be downloaded.

Comment: apparently the jar files doesn't even exist starting from version 6.0.0,
here's where maven get the files: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/6.1.4.Final/